# Where are all my Empathy settings stored?

Tags: backup, empathy

I would like to know where Empathy stores all my information, so as to be able to back it up and re-use on a different Ubuntu machine.

So far I have found only the conversation logs in `~/.local/share/Empathy`

Any idea where the rest is (account information, buddies, favorite rooms, etc?)

Answer (score 23):

From the [Empathy FAQ](http://live.gnome.org/Empathy/FAQ#Where_does_Empathy_save_files_.28accounts.2C_logs.2C_configuration.29.3F):

> **Where does Empathy save files (accounts, logs, configuration)?**
>
> - Accounts settings are saved in `~/.mission-control/accounts/accounts.cfg` (except passwords which are stored in gnome-keyring).
> - New logs (since Empathy 2.31.4) are saved in `~/.local/share/TpLogger/logs`
> - Old logs are saved in `~/.local/share/Empathy/logs/`
> - Empathy configuration is stored in DConf and `~/.config/Empathy/`
> - Avatars are cached in `~/.cache/telepathy/avatars/`

[Meta-contacts](http://treitter.livejournal.com/12309.html) are stored in the file:

```
~/.local/share/folks/relationships.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

I could have sworn they were moved to somewhere in `~/.local`, but it looks like accounts are still stored in `~/.mission-control`. If you also want your saved passwords for accounts, you'll need to copy your GNOME keyring as well, which is in `~/.gnome2/keyrings`.